# Tabs in Foundation CSS

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I am designing my website project based on Foundation CSS in responsive view. Because I need to add tabs, I went through this site http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/tabs.php. I need to add **pill-style** tab.

```
<dl class="tabs pill">
  <dd class="active"><a href="#pillTab1">Pill Tab 1</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#pillTab2">Pill Tab 2</a></dd>
  <dd class="hide-for-small"><a href="#pillTab3">Pill Tab 3</a></dd>
</dl>
```

I have added this code. I got just pill Tab 1, pill Tab 2, pill Tab 3. I am not getting the pill sytle tab. What are the steps I need to do?

Comment: Stupid question but did you include the Foundation CSS file?

Comment: Where is the css for 'active' and 'hide-for-small' classes?

Comment: How are you getting it right now? The code seems correct. Can you post a screenshot? And do you have any other tabs with the same IDs?

Comment: i have added this js files for tabs  <script src="<?= base_url(); ?>foundation/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>foundation/js/jquery.foundation.tabs.js"></script>

Comment: Pls code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @sangeetha if you are not getting the styles that means you are not getting the css.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle for you and this seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Wj48a/

But the "pill tabs" you are referring to are only present in older versions of the foundation framework (3.x) and no longer available in 4.x. In newer versions of foundation the same style can be achieved with subnav: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/sub-nav.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working here  http://jsfiddle.net/KD2bS/2/

Please add a script

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.foundation.tabs.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
    $(document).foundationTabs();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Working for me i n jsfiddle , Please show your code in fiddle

Comment: You should call jquery (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js) in top of the all js file

Comment: i need name textfield for native tab and name,email for multi app tab

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script> after including this line class active is working shibin thanks

Comment: but how to give seperate data for two tabs

Comment: I dont understand , Sorry , Already added different data in each "dd" tag

Comment: jsfiddle.net/sangeetha_xvalue/FYh8T/3    have u visit this link